# Link is set to active in a sub route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I noticed that when I'm in the route `forums.archives`, my link defined using `{{#link-to 'forums'}}Forums{{/link-to}}` is set with the class active.

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('forums', function () {
        this.route('new');
        this.route('archives');
    });
});
```

Navigation:

```
{{#link-to 'forums'}}Forums{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'forums.archives'}}Forum archives{{/link-to}}
```

Both of them got the active class.

Is there a way to remove the active class on the link if it doesn't match 100% with the url?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your router map (at least the `forums` part of it)?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a nested `route`, and to be honest, I have no idea how it works. The word from the Ember team is that it works the same as nested resources, but there are a lot of subtleties (like this one) that don't really make sense. So here's what I would do (which might not be what you *should* do). Assuming that your navigation is in your `application` template:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isForumsActive: function() {
        return (this.get('currentRouteName') === 'forums');
    }.property('currentRouteName')
});
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{#link-to 'forums' active=isForumsActive}}Forums{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'forums.archives'}}Forum archives{{/link-to}}
```

You might also want to change up how your routes so that nesting is a little cleaner:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('forums', function () {
        // this.route('index'); -- implicitly defined
        this.route('new');
        this.route('archives');
    });
});
```

Then your `link-to` could point to `forums.index` instead.